# Sum of primes. No matter where I cast long to int, my sum of primes results in a memory heap

Tags: java, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I think I'm using the Eratosthenes sieve, since an array can't take long values as indexes, I get the memory error even when  I use casting. Should I rather create a Map or List containing long values and compute that way ?
This is the code:
**

```
int max = 2000000;
    int sum = 0;
    boolean[] list = new boolean[max];

    list[0] = false;
    list[1] = false;
    for (int i = 2; i < max; i++) {
      list[i] = true;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < max; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < max; j++) {      
        if(list[j]&&i*j<max){        
          list[i*j] = false;
        }
      }
      if(list[i]){
      sum+=i;     
      }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

**

Comment: Where exactly are you hitting the memory error?

Comment: The range for the int type is `-2^32` to `+2^32`. How come you are getting OOM already? Are you sure it's not a Java heap size error? Can you post your error log?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2000000; index=-2147464558

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.duy.android.compiler.java.Java.run(Java.java:115)
 at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.executeDex(ExecuteActivity.java:147)
 at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.exec(ExecuteActivity.java:124)
 at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.access$100(ExecuteActivity.java:45)
 at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity$1.run(ExecuteActivity.java:88)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the expression `i*j` is overflowing the `int` type.

You can try casting each to a `long` before multiplying.

E.g.,

public class HelloWorld{

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    int i = 200000;
    int j = 20000;
    System.out.println("i*j = " + (i*j));
    System.out.println("(long) i*(long j) = " + ((long) i*(long) j));
 }
```

}

> ```
> $javac HelloWorld.java
> $java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld
> i*j = -294967296
> (long) i*(long j) = 4000000000
> ```